# Java 8: cast list of POJO to map - ID-POJO = map (Function<? super C, ?>) in Stream cannot be applied to (<lambda expression>, <lambda expression>)

Tags: java, list, collections, lambda, java-stream

How fix this?

**Error**

map (Function)
in Stream cannot be applied
to (lambda expression>, lambda expression>)

```
static class C {
    int id;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
}

    Map<Integer, C> c = Arrays.asList(new C()).stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(c -> c.getId(), c -> c));
```

Comment: That's not the way `map()` works. It does not  create a `Map`.

Comment: yes, missed collect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
 Map<Integer, C> map = Arrays.asList(new C())
                          .stream()
                          .collect(Collectors.toMap(C::getId, c -> c));
```

What map does in your example is change the object in the stream from one thing to another. e.g. You have a stream of `C` objects, and then `map(c -> c.getId())` would change that to a stream of `Integers`. What you were looking for is the `collect` function which terminates the stream and allows you to "collect" it to whatever object you are trying to get to

Comment: `Arrays.asList(new C()).stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(C::getId, Function.identity()));`

Comment: I've always found Function.identity to be a lot more verbose than just doing x -> x